# Bash script to extract 10 most common double-vowels word form a file

Tags: regex, grep

So I have tried to write a Bash script to extract the 10 most common double-vowels words from a file, like good, teeth, etc.
Here is what I have so far:

```
grep -E -o '[aeiou]{2}' $1|tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' |sort|uniq -c|sort -n | tail -10
```

I tried to use grep with flag E, then find the pattern match, such as 'aa', 'ee', 'ii' , etc, but it is not working at all,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1BTN.png), what I got back, just 'ai', 'ea', something like this. Can anyone help me figure how to do pattern match in bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply match any amount of letters before or after a repeated vowel with this POSIX ERE regex with a GNU `grep`:

```sh
grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]*([aeiou])\1[[:alpha:]]*' words.txt
```

FreeBSD (non-GNU) grep does not support a backreference in the pattern, so you will have to list all possible vowel sequences:

```sh
grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]*(aa|ee|ii|oo|uu)[[:alpha:]]*' words.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/wp5WCN):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Some good feed
Soot and weed'
grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]*([aeiou])\1[[:alpha:]]*' <<< "$s"
```

*Details*:

- `[[:alpha:]]*` - zero or more letters
- `(aa|ee|ii|oo|uu)` - one of the char sequences, `aa`, `ee`, `ii`, `oo` or `uu` (`|` is an alternation operator in a POSIX ERE regex)
- `([aeiou])` - Group 1: a vowel
- `\1` - the same vowel as in Group 1
- `[[:alpha:]]*` - zero or more letters

See the diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to change your regex: replace `[aeiou]{2}` with `aa|ee|ii|oo|uu`.  (This does not fix the issue of only finding the match rather than the full word.)

Answer (score 1):

Building on Andrew's answer (re: matching double vowels):

```
$ cat words.txt
good food;foul make chicken,eek too brave
eye you yuu something:three food too tu too

$ grep -E -o '\<[[:alnum:]]*(aa|ee|ii|oo|uu)[[:alnum:]]*\>' words.txt
good
food
eek
too
yuu
three
food
too
too
```

The `grep` finds only words (`\<` and `\>` represent word boundaries) with letters and/or digits *and* containing a dual vowel, printing each word on a separate line.

Applying the rest of OP's counting/sorting logic:

```
$ grep -E -o '\<[[:alnum:]]*(aa|ee|ii|oo|uu)[[:alnum:]]*\>' words.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 eek
      1 good
      1 three
      1 yuu
      2 food
      3 too
```